# ASP.NET Core 6 Identity Login White on Yellow Text

Tags: colors, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have a website which uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`.

When the login page appears, the text in email and password is almost invisible as it is white on yellow. This was working fine for a while but something I have done has caused the black text to change to white which makes it almost unreadable.

I have another website in ASP.NET Core 3 which is white on white so it's impossible to see. My guess is that it may be something in the Bootstrap files but nothing I do seems to improve it and it has identical Bootstrap files to another website that doesn't have this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check the custom stylesheets in your site to make sure they are not overriding the color settings for the text in the login form. You can also use your browser's developer tools to inspect the style of the element to determine how the text color is set and Which style rule is inherited from. You can also check whether the Bootstrap related color scheme has been customized. If that still doesn't solve the problem can you provide a simple example of the problem?(About the login page code and related css)